# Include css and js files from vendor library via assets in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, template-engine

I want to include `css` and `js` files from a library in my vendor directory into Twig.

I downloaded `morrisjs` via composer into my vendor directory of symfony. Now I want to include the main `css` und `js` files into my Twig Template. But as far as I know the `asset` function only works with files that are located in Bundles.

The files I want to include are located in the following paths:

- *project\vendor\morrisjs\morris.js\morris.js*
- *project\vendor\morrisjs\morris.js\morris.css*

I thought about some theoretical code that would look like that:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('vendor/morrisjs/morris.js/morris.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any possibility to include these files directly from vendor and how when not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `morrisjs` is a frontend javascript library then install it via `npm` or `bower`.

Packages installed via `composer` should have all their public assets in `Resources/public` so you can publish them using:

```
$ php bin/console assets:install target [--symlink]
```

Then in a twig template use just:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/contact.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

After installing new packages, run:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

'web' being your server's document root(public_html or whatever it is).
You also need to dump your assets:

```
//for dev
php app/console assetic:dump
//for prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

In your servers public root, you will have directory /bundles/ where all your files will be present, and you can easily include them in Twig with {{ asset('bundles/morri..) }}

Read up on [combining assets](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/assetic/php.html), something you will need at some point.